# C# compiler gets Environment namespace wrong after I add a new dll

Tags: c#

I have an existing C# file, A.cs, which uses `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()` in `System`. I have `using System;` in the beginning of the file. It compiles fine.

And in another file, B.cs, in the same project, I need to add `using AnotherNamespace.Environment.APackage`. So I need to add a new reference dll to my project.

B.cs compiles fine. but A.cs has compiler error saying `GetEnvironmentVariable()` does not exist in `AnotherNamespace.Environment`.

I would like to know why the compiler thinks that Environment is from `AnotherNamespace.Environment` instead of `System`? I did not change A.cs file at all.

Comment: .NET getting confused because your project name contains "Environment" in its namespace. When checking for b.cs, its search for GetEnvironmentVariable() in your package & see nothing, hence it throws the error.

Comment: Could you post the actual using directives from both files?

Comment: And also all the namespace declarations surrounding the error. They are relevant.

Comment: Likely can be resolved by moving the `using System;` line from the beginning of the file to within the namespace declaration, just above the `class A` declaration.

Comment: Could you please post a [mcve] of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to avoid namespace collisions, you either need to explicitly specify usage, as per

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()
```

Or a `using` alias, as per

```
using Environment = System.Environment;
```

However, either of these should only be necessary if A.cs contains `using AnotherNamespace`. This error can also occur if the malfucntioning code is contained with `AnotherNamespace`, including being within a nested namespace such as `AnotherNamespace.Nest.Something`.